# Can't use $_GET as a numerical indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, get, indexing, numeric

i am at prototype stage. I have a link in page1.php that sends to page below:

```
http://localhost/sayfa.php?rd_dil=turkish&rd_sayfa=yazilar&rd_yazar=ali_uysal&rd_baslik=kalem_ucu"
```

in this page, `echo $_GET['rd_dil']` works and displays `turkish` but echo $_GET[0] displays a `Notice : Undefined offset: 0`

so I want to work with $_GET in numerical way (numerical index) ? how can I achieve this aim? I read php.net + stack overflow and googled but I couldn't solve my issue.

Comment: associated array; read only.

Comment: And then someone accesses your site through `http://localhost/sayfa.php?rd_sayfa=yazilar&rd_dil=turkish&...` (swapping the first and second parameters) and everything crashes spectacularly.

Comment: @DoSparKot Read-only, well it should be, but you can do with it whatever you want

Comment: @axel.michel I just found out & I'm puzzled. :-O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$_GET is an assoziative array, to loop over it:

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value) {
   ....
}
```

In case you want only the values in a numeric array, you could use:

```
$myData = array_values($_GET);
// here you have a numeric array containing the $_GET values
echo $myData[0];
```

Comment: Can someone explain the down-vote please? The Question was simple, this is not about is a good idea to do it, or why would you do it. Just about "how to transfer it".

Answer (score 2):

Since `$_GET` is an associate array, you can assign the values to a new array:

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$val) {
   $_GET2[] = $val;
}
```

Or you can use `array_values` as suggested by axel.michel:

```
$_GET2 = array_values($_GET);
echo $_GET2[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do that directly. But there are some workarounds:

```
$indexed = array_values($_GET);
$first = $indexed[0];

$keys = array_keys($_GET);
$first = $_GET[$keys[0]];

$first = current(array_slice(array('foo'), 0, 1)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can't. That's just how it works.
There is just no such index.

You don't need numerical indexes though, but have to use associative keys.

There are 2 reasons why you shouldn't translate your $_GET into enumerated list:

- parameter order is not guaranteed. you **have** to use field names instead of positions.
- it's just useless waste of CPU. Everything you want from your enumerated array, you can get from  original $_GET. Use `foreach()` to iterate it for example.

If you still don't know how to handle $_GET properly - ask this very question, and you will get the proper answer.

Comment: @Your Common Sense So can you please guide me that How can I pass my $_GET to a custom array if my $_GET count varies so I think with my custom array I can use numerical indexes. BR.